# Use existing encrypted directory as home directory

Tags: linux, home, ecryptfs

In the past, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with `/dev/sda4` mounted as `/home`. I encrypted my home directory.

Today, I erased all the partitions except `/dev/sda4` and I installed Xubuntu 14.04 on a new partition (`/dev/sda3`). I did not mount `/dev/sda4`.

Then I used usermod to change my home directory from /home/jordan to `/home-old/jordan`. Then I mounted `/dev/sda4` as `/home`.

Now I want to change my current home directory from `/home-old/jordan` to `/home/jordan`, keeping the original (encrypted) contents of `/home/jordan`.

How can I do this? (I know both the login password and the ecryptfs passphrase used to encrypt the old home directory.)

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point is the [mount.ecryptfs_private(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mount.ecryptfs_private.1.html) man page and the ecryptfs-mount-private(1) interactive command.
Beware, I have never used this; on my ubuntu 14.04 I opted for encrypted home dirs and I now have
a per-user directory `/home/.ecryptfs/user/.ecryptfs/` with encryption info in several files, 
and `/home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private/` with the encrypted data.

When I login it seems the pam module `pam_ecryptfs(8)` uses my login password to unwrap the passphrase,
add it to my kernel keyring, and do the mount. I end up with `/home/user/`. Private mounted on `/home/user`.

`/usr/share/doc/ecryptfs-utils/README.gz` has more info.